# How could I stop the plotshape since another plotshape shows up?

Tags: pine-script

I am new to PineScript and I have an open-source script for tradingview.

My goal is that after heikin-ashi BUY or SELL signal shows up it calculates the percentage of change in BUY or SELL trend candle (which is the `percUP` `percDOWN` and "x" plotshape for the alert)

It works but I want the "x" plotshapes only to show up when the candle is on BUY trend not on SELL trend. (same with SELL trend)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB3uC.jpg -> This is the current state of the script.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSWo9.jpg -> This is my goal.
(Sorry to link it. They're not allowed to post an image here.)

That is out of my hand. Any hints or help is much appreciated!

```html
//@version=5

indicator('heikin ashi alert', overlay=true)
EMAlength = input(15, 'EMA LENGTH?')

src = ohlc4
haOpen = 0.0
haOpen := (src + nz(haOpen[1])) / 2
haC = (ohlc4 + nz(haOpen) + math.max(high, nz(haOpen)) + math.min(low, nz(haOpen))) / 4
EMA1 = ta.ema(haC, EMAlength)
EMA2 = ta.ema(EMA1, EMAlength)
EMA3 = ta.ema(EMA2, EMAlength)
TMA1 = 3 * EMA1 - 3 * EMA2 + EMA3
EMA4 = ta.ema(TMA1, EMAlength)
EMA5 = ta.ema(EMA4, EMAlength)
EMA6 = ta.ema(EMA5, EMAlength)
TMA2 = 3 * EMA4 - 3 * EMA5 + EMA6
IPEK = TMA1 - TMA2
YASIN = TMA1 + IPEK
EMA7 = ta.ema(hlc3, EMAlength)
EMA8 = ta.ema(EMA7, EMAlength)
EMA9 = ta.ema(EMA8, EMAlength)
TMA3 = 3 * EMA7 - 3 * EMA8 + EMA9
EMA10 = ta.ema(TMA3, EMAlength)
EMA11 = ta.ema(EMA10, EMAlength)
EMA12 = ta.ema(EMA11, EMAlength)
TMA4 = 3 * EMA10 - 3 * EMA11 + EMA12
IPEK1 = TMA3 - TMA4
YASIN1 = TMA3 + IPEK1

mavi = YASIN1
kirmizi = YASIN

longCond = mavi > kirmizi and mavi[1] <= kirmizi[1] 
shortCond = mavi < kirmizi and mavi[1] >= kirmizi[1]

trendState = kirmizi < mavi ? true : kirmizi > mavi ? false : na
closePlot = plot(kirmizi, title='Close Line', color=color.new(#009900, 90), linewidth=10, style=plot.style_line)
openPlot = plot(mavi, title='Open Line', color=color.new(#CC0000, 90), linewidth=10, style=plot.style_line)
closePlotU = plot(trendState ? kirmizi : na, editable=false, transp=100)
openPlotU = plot(trendState ? mavi : na, editable=false, transp=100)
closePlotD = plot(trendState ? na : kirmizi, editable=false, transp=100)
openPlotD = plot(trendState ? na : mavi, editable=false, transp=100)
fill(openPlotU, closePlotU, title='Up Trend Fill', color=color.new(#009900, 1))
fill(openPlotD, closePlotD, title='Down Trend Fill', color=color.new(#CC0000, 1))


last_signal = 0
long_final = longCond and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1) 
short_final = shortCond and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == 1)


alertcondition(long_final, title='buy alarm', message='buy signal!!!')
alertcondition(short_final, title='sell alarm', message='sell signal!!!')

last_signal := long_final ? 1 : short_final ? -1 : last_signal[1]

plotshape(long_final, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), size=size.tiny, title='buy label', text='BUY', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(short_final, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.tiny, title='sell label', text='SELL', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))


// this is the code 

percUP = ((high - open) / open) * 100
percUP := math.round(percUP, 2) // roundup

percDOWN = ((low - open) / open) * 100
percDOWN := math.round(percDOWN, 2) // roundup


lTrend = ta.barssince(long_final[1]) and percUP < 0.1 
sTrend = ta.barssince(short_final[1]) and percDOWN > -0.1


plotshape(lTrend, style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), size=size.tiny, title='buy X label', textcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
plotshape(sTrend, style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.tiny, title='buy X label', textcolor=color.new(color.red, 0))


plot(percUP, style=plot.style_columns, color=color.new(#00ffaa, 90))
plot(percDOWN, style=plot.style_columns, color=color.new(color.red, 90))


// alert 
    
// alertcondition(lTrend[1], title='alert1', message='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `var` for the trend direction. Then plot the `x`s if the trend direction matches.

```
lTrend = ta.barssince(long_final[1]) and percUP < 0.1 
sTrend = ta.barssince(short_final[1]) and percDOWN > -0.1

var is_up_trend = false

is_up_trend := long_final ? true : short_final ? false : is_up_trend

plotshape(lTrend and is_up_trend, style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), size=size.tiny, title='buy X label', textcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
plotshape(sTrend and not is_up_trend, style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.tiny, title='buy X label', textcolor=color.new(color.red, 0))
```

Comment: This code works perfectly well and is exactly what I wanted about it. Thank you so much for the code